# How to add PNG asset as IconData?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, png

I have png asset and I want to put it as Icon, but solutions that I found are not working.

Here is what I have now:

```
GradientIcon(
          ImageIcon(
            AssetImage('assets/svg/icons/discoball'),
          ),
          size.width * 0.15,
          const LinearGradient(
            stops: [
              0.25,
              0.75,
            ],
            colors: [Color(0xffff7a00), Color(0xffff00d6)],
          ),
        ),
```

and this is GradientIcon class

```
class GradientIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientIcon(
    this.icon,
    this.size,
    this.gradient,
  );

  final IconData icon;
  final double? size;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: size! * 2,
        height: size! * 1.2,
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          size: size,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return gradient.createShader(bounds);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and I am getting this error

```
The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'.
```

Why this is not working? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `GradientIcon` that will accept widget.

```dart
class GradientIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientIcon(
    this.child,
    this.size,
    this.gradient,
    {super.key}
  );

  final Widget child;
  final double? size;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: size! * 2,
        height: size! * 1.2,
        child: child,
      ),
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return gradient.createShader(bounds);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I would prefer named constructor

```dart
const GradientIcon({
  Key? key,
  required this.child,
  this.size,
  required this.gradient,
}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: It's working but gradient is not displaying. It's not possible on png?

Comment: You like to show gradient icon?

Comment: Yes, my png icon is black and is displaying as black, but I want it with gradient

Comment: Can you try providing some color on `AssetImage`

Comment: I don't think so as AssetImage has 3 parameters, asset name, AssetBundle and String package.
ImageIcon has parameter color but it's not possible to assign LinearGradient to this

Comment: Oh sorry, try on `ImageIcon`

Comment: as in edited comment above, ImageIcon has Color parameter, I can't assign LinearGradient to this, I am not sure about this, but I don't think it's possible

Comment: I mean can you just test with providing some color on `ImageIcon` and use the `GradientIcon` as well,

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to FlutterIcon.com
2. Drag and drop all your Icons
3. Give a class name (Let's say CustomIcons)
4. Download and Unzip.
5. Copy fonts folder to your app folder and add the fonts as you add a normal font in flutter. (See here how to add a custom font).
6. Copy custom class CustomIcons that we generated to your lib directory.
7. Use CustomIcons as IconData :

   ```
    Icon(CustomIcons.hamburger)
   ```